# Excel - Returning value only from current and 3 previous rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet with 3 columns. Column 1 is a list of Jurisdiction Types (State, City, County and District) and Column 2 is the Name of the corresponding Jurisdiction.

I need to combine some of the names in Column 2 into a string that displays in Column 3, depending on their corresponding "Jurisdiction Type" in Column 1 as such:

1. State and City names will not change and will basically just reappear in Column 3
2. I am appending the city to the county names
3. I am appending the county names to the district names.
4. In cases where "Not Applicable" is a value: If it is a state or city, it will be shown in Column 3 but I am eliminating "Not Applicable" from any strings (so it will not be appended to any county or district names).

My formula is:

```
=IF(A13="State", B13, IF(A13="City",IF(A13="NOT APPLICABLE", "NOT APPLICABLE", B13),IF(A13="County",IF(A13="NOT APPLICABLE", "NOT APPLICABLE", IF(VLOOKUP("City", A10:B13,2, FALSE)="NOT APPLICABLE", B13, VLOOKUP("City", A10:B13,2, FALSE) & " " & B13)),IF(A13="District",IF(B13="NOT APPLICABLE", "NOT APPLICABLE", IF(VLOOKUP("County", A10:B13,2,FALSE)="NOT APPLICABLE", B13, VLOOKUP("County", A10:B13,2, FALSE) & " " & B13))))))
```

I've been able to accomplish the above and everything seems to be working okay. However, I am worried about the way I've used `VLOOKUP` to find the data. This is a very long list and as I drag the formula down, the `VLOOKUP` range changes. So, for example, in the 4th row, the range is A2:B5 but then as I drag it down, it becomes A3:B6, A4:B7, etc. I'm wondering if, there is a way to alter the range in the VLOOKUP function or if I should be using another function altogether in order to instruct the formula to always only look in the current row plus the 3 rows prior.

Here is a sample of my spreadsheet:

[image: Jurisdiction Table]

I tried to make columns but couldn't figure out how to do it in Stack Exchange so ended up just making a screenshot. I hope it's okay.

Comment: For tasks as complex as this you may want to consider Visual Basic, a programming language often used with Excel. It has the capacity to iterate down every row, which would reduce the risk of using VLOOKUP. I know that's not of much use when you've already invested this much time in a formula, but It might be worth thinking about for next time.

Comment: Thank you! I have very little experience with Visual Basic so hoped I could accomplish this with a regular formula. However, really appreciate the suggestion and will definitely work harder to learn VB faster...I have run into many instances where it would be invaluable. Cheers. :-)

Comment: Is there a possibility that both City & County are NOT APPLICABLE? Should this condition be also factored in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula in Column 3 and see if this works for you. My assumption is that State City County & District repeat every 4 rows consistently thruout.

```
=IF(A2="State",B2,IF(A2="City",B2,IF(OR(A2="County",A2="District"),IF(AND(B2="NOT APPLICABLE",B1="NOT APPLICABLE"),"",IF(B1="NOT APPLICABLE",B2,IF(B2="NOT APPLICABLE",B1,IF(AND(B1<>"NOT APPLICABLE",B2<>"NOT APPLICABLE"),B1&" "&B2,"")))))))
```

I have replaced VLOOKUP with absolute cell references. It needs at least one spare row on top to begin with, which is your header anyway.

[image]

Comment: pat2015-This is absolutely gorgeous, thank you! Works perfectly! Big huge thanks to you for not only solving my puzzle but also for cleaning up my mess of a formula. Really like your use of IF/AND rather than all my VLOOKUPs. Thank you very very much for your help!!!!